# is there any command in cmd prompt similar to cut -d in unix?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a file foo which contains the below content.

Exception/BatchUpdateException/SQLException 755BJX/5268501774913
Exception/BatchUpdateException/SQLException 5DL9E4/5268501583930
Exception/BatchUpdateException/SQLException 5NHBDO/5268501765579

I need only the below output from the content.

755BJX,5268501774913

5DL9E4,5268501583930

5NHBDO,5268501765579

Could you please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in (c:\temp\log.txt)  do call :parse %%i 

:parse
set text=%1 
echo %text:/=,%
```

explaination :
We read each line of the logfile, take the second part ( right side of the space, as  is a default delimiter.
Then we assign this to a variable and we use in place substitution to convert `/`to `,`

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

```
for /F "tokens=4,5 delims=/ " %%a in (test.txt) do echo %%a,%%b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%I IN (test.txt) DO FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%J IN ("%%I") DO @echo %%J,%%K
```

Comment: Either of the answers works, downloading Unix utils for Windows is maybe a better answer.